# Running a global mouse hook in a background thread

Tags: c#

I am running a global mouse hook from the main UI thread but wanted to run it in a background thread (comments appreciated), not sure how to achieve this. I am running some UIA code on background MTA thread but on updating the UI on the main thread the mouse becomes somewhat jerky when the user interface is being built for my application.  I have tried cancelling all UIA event handlers in the application which were running on background MTA threads but still get the jerky mouse problem

Many thanks

```
MouseHook.MouseAction += new EventHandler(MouseHook_MouseAction);
            MouseHook.Start();

  private void MouseHook_MouseAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do whatever

    }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace myApp
{
    public static class MouseHook
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
          LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]


        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
          IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        public static event EventHandler MouseAction = delegate { };

        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
          //  WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            //WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
           WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        public static void Start()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

        }
        public static void stop()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }

        private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle("user32"), 0);
                if (hook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
                return hook;
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
          int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam || MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam ))                   
            {
                MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                MouseAction(null, new EventArgs());
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 'I am running a global mouse hook on the main UI thread but wanted to run it in a background thread', is that not something your OS (a.k.a. Windows) does do for you?

Comment: Well I thought so but trying to troubleshoot why the mouse is jerky just for a few seconds when the UI is being built?

Comment: Well I should say 1 second or a split second but trying to resolve nonetheless.

Comment: After the mouse click triggered the build of the UI I immediately stopped the mousehook until the UI was built and then I started the mousehook again and that seems to stop it!